# Integrating whatwasit and ex_admin

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to introduce audit logging for all phoenix models using [whatwasit](https://github.com/smpallen99/whatwasit). The codebase uses [ex_admin](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin) for an admin-section.
According to the whatwasit docs, we need to add an extra parameter to the `changeset` method in the model, and invoke `prepare_version` with this optional 3rd parameter. With this, I am able to generate a version in the `versions` table when the model is saved (tested using iex).

But, there doesn't seem to be an example where the resource_controller (from ex_admin) allows hooks to capture the currently logged-in user, and then use that in the defined structure to be passed in as the 3rd argument to the `changeset` method.
What I have tried is to introduce a before_filter in the controller block to capture the current user:

```
controller do
  before_filter :capture_audit_settings, only: [:create]

  def capture_audit_settings(conn, params) do
    user = Coherence.current_user(conn)
    audit_settings = [whodoneit: user, whodoneit_name: user.name]

    Module.put_attribute(__MODULE__, :audit_settings, audit_settings)
    conn
  end
end

changesets create: &__MODULE__.create_changeset/2

def create_changeset(model, params) do
  tmp = Module.get_attribute(__MODULE__, :audit_settings)
  # TODO: Need to invoke the changeset/3 method that is defined in the model with tmp as the 3rd parameter
end
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: `Module.put_attribute` will not work like that; it's only available before the given module is compiled.

Comment: @Dogbert - yes, that is the error I am getting, but can you think of a different way to capture the current user, and have it available for `whatwasit`? I also tried putting it into the `conn.assigns` - but, that would mean that the model will now need to know about `conn`.